# Manipulation H1 Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Problem:

```
<h1 id="title">Text Text Text <br> Second Text Text Text </h1>
```

How can i change or manipulate the Text after the break-Tag ?

**I cant change the HTML itself** and it has to be done via JavaScript containing  jQuery.

After manipulating it should look like this:

```
<h1 id="title">Text Text Text <br> <span id="preTitle"> blablabla </span></h1>
```

Anybody got a solution to this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the initial html inside `h1` tag. Split it by `br` tag. Adjust the second part of splited html with `span` tag. Join splited parts with `br` tag and put them back into `h1` tag:

```js
var html = $("#title").html();
var parts = html.split("<br>");
parts[1] = "<span class='preTitle'>"+parts[1]+"</span>";
$("#title").html(parts.join("<br>"));
```

```css
.preTitle{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title">Text Text Text <br> Second Text Text Text </h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast solution :)

Comment: do you know what is possible when u cant use split? because IE8 doesnt understand that

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery:

```
var titleHtml = $("#title").html().split('<br>');
$("#title").html(titleHtml[0]+"<br><span id='preTitle'>"+titleHtml[1]+"</span>");
```